Separation Theorem on Complex Vector Spaces

Let $V$ be a complex normed vector space. A set $A$ is open and convex and $\forall x \in A, |\alpha|\le 1, \alpha x\in A$, and $B$ is a non-empty convex set such that $A\cap B =\emptyset$. Prove that there exists a complex linear functional $f$ on $V$ and $c>0$, such that $|f(x)|<c, \forall x \in A$ and $|f(x)|\ge c, \forall x \in B$.

I have proved one Hahn-Banach theorem on complex vector spaces, that is if $V$ is a complex vector space, $V_0$ is a subspace of $V$, $p$ is a semi-norm on $V$, and $f_0:V_0\to \mathbb C$ is a linear functional that satisfies $|f_0(x)|\le p(x), \forall x \in V_0$, then there exists a linear functional $f$ on $V$, $f(x)=f_0(x),\forall x\in V_0$ and $|f(x)|\le p(x), \forall x \in V$.
In the real case, we can construct a Minkowski functional $p_M(x):=\inf_{\alpha>0,\alpha^{-1}x\in M} \alpha$, when $M$ is convex and  $\forall x\in M, |\alpha|=1$,  $\alpha x\in M$. And in the proof of a similar problem in the real case, we apply the Hahn-Banach theorem to the set $A-B:=\{a-b:a\in A, b\in B\}$.
But in the complex case, how to prove this problem? Many thanks in advance!

In the complex Hahn-Banach theorem, it is sufficient that $p$ is a sublinear functional, i.e., $p(x+y) \le p(x) + p(y)$ and $p(\alpha x) = \alpha p(x)$ for all $\alpha \ge 0$. This should apply to $p_{A-B}$. (In this version of Hahn-Banach one only gets an assertion for the real part, so it might not help for your problem)
